# Unable to Marshal.dump Google Protobuf Repeated Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, protocol-buffers, marshalling

I am trying the following:

```
Rails.cache.fetch(key, expires_in: 1.day) do
    Some Protobuf Model
end
```

And I am getting:

> TypeError: no _dump_data is defined for class
>   Google::Protobuf::RepeatedField

Since I have a repeated string in the model.
How can this be solved?

Comment: Can't you dump a protocol buffer to a simple byte string and cache that rather than trying to rely on `Marshal`?

Comment: @muistooshort - it is less efficient

Comment: Are you sure about that? And if you are, is the difference enough to worry about? Also, why wouldn't you parse a protocol buffer into native Ruby data structures to use the data in a Ruby environment? How much data interchange or RPC work are you doing once you're in Ruby?

Comment: @muistooshort - OMG, I did not convert the repeatedfield to array! Thanks.

Comment: No worries, some of the hardest bugs to see are the ones hiding right out in the open :)

Answer (score 0):

Himberjack already solved his problem, but I'll add my own (different) solution here in case it helps others.

When I'm caching a protobuf message I use `encode` to convert it to a string for the cache, and `decode` to convert it back to a protobuf message. These methods are called from the class of the protobuf message

```
def proto_cache_fetch(proto_class, key, options)
  data = Rails.cache.fetch(key, options) do
    proto_class.encode(yield)
  end
  proto_class.decode(data)
end
```

then you can do this:

```
proto_cache_fetch(MyMessage, key, expires_in: 1.day) do
  MyMessage.new(attr: 'value')
end
```